# fadein/out slow doesn't have the "slow" effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

The below code should fade in and out. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 910){
        $('#logopiano').stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $(this).show().css({ visibility: "visible" });
        });
    } else {
        $('#logopiano').stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).show().css({ visibility: "hidden" });
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the page: http://ffio.it/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `scroll` event fires once for every pixel scrolled. This means that the `fade` is started, but on the next pixel is stopped and the end result is immediately shown. To stop this you can run your code a few seconds after the scrolling stops, by using `setTimeout`. Try this:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var $logopiano = $('#logopiano').stop(true, true);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 910) {
            $logopiano.fadeIn("slow", function() {
                $(this).show().css({ visibility: "visible" });
            });
        } else {
            $logopiano.fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).show().css({ visibility: "hidden" });
            });
        }
    }, 100); // execute 100ms after scrolling stops. Amend as needed.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried but result is the same.. here is the code live: http://ffio.it/index.html

Comment: See my code, do you think it's ok? :)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30064994/2463218

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working snippet:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $logopiano = $('#logopiano');

function showHideLogo() {
   if( $window.scrollTop() > 910 ) {
        $logopiano.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        });
   } else {
        $logopiano.fadeOut("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}

showHideLogo();
$window.scroll(showHideLogo);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. You mix up between fadeOut and fadeIn function. Switch them and code works perfectly.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 910){
    $('#logopiano').stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $this.show().css({ visibility: "visible" });
    });
} else {
    $('#logopiano').stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $this.show().css({ visibility: "hidden" });
    });
}
});
```